# cookie loaded from file is encoded in setcookie

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm trying to get a cookie using curl , and then set it.

i'm using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie.txt')` to save the cookie to a file.

And then these commands to set the cookie:

```
$cookie = file_get_contents('/tmp/cookie.txt');
setcookie('CAKEPHP', $cookie, 0, '/', 'moxo-adhdtest.com', false, true);
```

This is the content of cookie.txt:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_.moxo-adhdtest.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1402594989  CAKEPHP tn1amoins09t7h94h05od1a4s4
```

And it is being saved to the browser encoded like that:
    `%23+Netscape+HTTP+Cookie+File%0A%23+http%3A%2F%2Fcurl.haxx.se%2Frfc%2Fcookie_spec.html%0A%23+This+file+was+generated+by+libcurl%21+Edit+at+your+own+risk.%0A%0A%23HttpOnly_.moxo-adhdtest.com%09TRUE%09%2F%09FALSE%091402594989%09CAKEPHP%09tn1amoins09t7h94h05od1a4s4%0`A

I tried to use **setrawcookie** and i get FALSE, so that doesn't help

How can i get it set correctly and not encoded?

Comment: You have to parse content of the file manually

Comment: Read this: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2005-03/0099.html

Comment: it explains about the cookie file structure.
You mean that the only way is to decode it using regex or something?

Comment: Sure. There is no other options